# Where is the dotnet internet explorer component cookies?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies

I would like to create my own internet explorer with C#.
But what about cookies? Does my own internet explorer uses system integrated IE's cookies that I don't want to or it is clearly apart from system integrated IE's cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The managed webbrowser control is just a managed wrapper around the native COM webbrowser control.  Thus your browser will still use wininet and it will store cookies in the same place as IE.